# Error with EF 4.1

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

Has anyone faced this error before with EF 4.1 code first?

A null was returned after calling the `GetService` method on a store provider instance of type `StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledOdbcProviderFactory`. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

I checked my connectionstring, it is fine and the same connectionstring is working fine for diff application. My DB is fine as well. And strangely it is happening on my machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you'll need to post some code for others to help you.

Comment: Don't use an out of date version. Use nuget package manager to get latest version of EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in EF 4.1 update 1. It is fixed in EF 4.2 and later. Please update to the latest version using NuGet.

Comment: But surprisingly all my team members dont have this problem. Is this could be because of newest version of nuget?